# J2EE JPA and class inheritance - Unknown column 'field list'

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, inheritance

Hi I am little bit desperate about one issue i have been struggling with. As a practise I am trying to build very simple ebanking app. So one table is called products (str productName, str descr), other is savingsAccounts(int accountNo, int clientNo, int balance). I have two classes:

***savingsAccount.java***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "savingsAccounts")  
@NamedQueries({  
@NamedQuery(name = "savingsAccount.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM savingsAccount s"),
@NamedQuery(name = "savingsAccount.findByClientNo", query = "SELECT s FROM savingsAccount s WHERE s.clientNo = :p_clientNo")
})

public class savingsAccount extends product implements Serializable {
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull  
@Column(name = "accountNo")  
private Integer accountNo;  
@Basic(optional = false)  
@NotNull  
@Column(name = "clientNo")  
private Integer clientNo;  
@Basic(optional = false)  
@NotNull  
@Column(name = "balance")  
private double balance;

//getters and setters nad constructorscode here
```

***product.java***

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "products")  
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)  
public class product implements Serializable {
@Id  
@Basic(optional = false)  
@NotNull  
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)  
@Column(name = "productName")  
public String productName;  

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "descr")
private String descr;
```

//gettes and setters and contructors

but when i run the namedquery savingsAccount.findByClientNo it gives me this statement:

```
SELECT accountNo, productName, balance, clientNo, descr FROM savingsAccounts WHERE (clientNo = ?)
```

it gives me this error:
Internal Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'descr' in 'field list'
```

I somehow "feel" that the issue is that there is no field called descr in savingsAccount table but i really do not know how to make it work... Thanks to all of you for help.

Comment: Thanks people for very useful hints. Maybe I will try to explain my motive to proceed this way. Maybe you wil ltell me it is completely wrong :). The reason was to make it flexible - e.g. when the product description would change, then one simple update in DB table would do the whole work and as far as all the savings accounts have the same description i tried to extend the class product.

Comment: The second reason was the displaying - all info needed to be displayed should be included in the same class - e.g. the overview of product would show in one row info about balance, accountNo, clientNo and the desired field descr. Maybe there is really some more elegant way... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class `savingsAccount` extends `product`, so it inherits the fields from that class. Hence in the corresponding table `savingsAccounts` there should also be columns for `descr` and `productName`.

Do an `alter table savingsAccounts add column descr varchar(255)` or similar, and another one for `productName`, and it should work.

Oh and I can't not say it: class names ought to start with a capital, like `Product`.

Answer (score 0):

About your problem :

Why are you extending "Products" on "SavingsAccount" ? If you're sure you need these, then you lack the corresponding columns on the "SavingAccounts" table, as geert3 said.

---

Can't post comments yet, sorry for the not relevant part, but still some feedback :

Why are you using @Basic annotation ? Doesn't seem useful here.

I don't see the advantage of your Inheritance strategy, but Oracle tutorial for JEE6 said quite a few things of TABLE_PER_CLASS. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html

Depending on your needs, you could also consider switching from namedqueries annotations to repositories interfaces, which provides basic queries automatically resolved by JPA, and separates your domain model from your queries.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_declaring_interfaces

And with the way you seem to configure your entity, you may not take the full advantage of it. For example, if your clientNo refers to a Client table/entity, you could then have something like

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //To adapt with the right relationship between savingsAccount/client 
@JoinColumn(name="clientNo")
private Client client;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are using `TABLE_PER_CLASS` then you should have 2 database tables with the following columns:

**Products**

- productName (the primary key)
- descr

**savingsAccounts**

- productName (inherited from products)
- descr (inherited from products)
- accountNo
- clientNo
- balance

However, I don't think that's what you want, is it? I think you have confused matters by making savingsAccounts inherit from products. If you don't specifically need inheritance in this case then I wouldn't use it.

By the way, you are using very verbose definitions of the columns in your entities.

Instead of:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "descr")
private String descr;
```

You can write:

```
@Column(name = "descr", length = 100, nullable = false)
private String descr;
```

In fact, if the database column name exactly matches the name of your Entity field, you don't even need to `name = ...`, thus:

```
@Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
private String descr;
```

The `@Basic` is assumed for basic data types (`String`, `Integer`, `Character`, etc.)